# Can I use an alternative build system for my Python extension module (written in C++)?

Tags: python, deployment, cmake, distutils, premake

While distutils works alright, I'm not entirely comfortable with it, and I also have performance problems with [no apparent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013851/speeding-up-build-process-with-distutils). Is it possible to integrate Premake or cmake in my setup.py script so that `python setup.py build` calls them and then places the output where install expects it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way, it's not pretty but it works.

Here is a summation of my `setup.py` script file - it should be fairly self explanatory:

```
import shutil
import os

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.core import Extension

from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
from distutils.command.install_lib import install_lib

library = None

def build_lib():
    """
        Build library and copy it to a temp folder.
        :returns: Location of the generated library is returned.
    """
    raise NotImplementedError

    
class MyInstall(install_lib):
    def install(self):
        global library
        shutil.move(library, self.install_dir)
        return [os.path.join(self.install_dir, library.split(os.sep)[-1])]


class MyBuildExtension(build_ext):
    def run(self):
        global library
        library = build_lib();

module = Extension('name',
                   sources=[])

setup(
    name='...',
    version='...',
    ext_modules=[module],
    description='...',
    long_description='...',
    author='...',
    author_email='...',
    url='...',
    keywords='...',
    license='...',
    platforms=[],
    classifiers=[],
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext': MyBuildExtension,
        'install_lib': MyInstall
    },
)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: On the contrary, this is a nice solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you think so. It might be the global variable that annoys me.